# Proof for continuity,partial derivatives and differentiablility in P(0,0)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Given are the two functions:
$f(x,y)=\sqrt [ 3 ]{ { x }^{ 2 }+{ y }^{ 2 } } \quad f(0,0)=0\\ f(x,y)=\frac { x*y }{ \sqrt { { x }^{ 2 }+{ y }^{ 2 } }  } $

Both functions are continous in (0,0) already checked this.
For the partial derivatives in P(0,0) both function got the value 0
I'm now having struggles to proof that they are not differentiable (my guess)
by using the Definition with a linear approximation f(x,y)=f(0,0)+L(x,y)+R(x,y)
since L(x,y) becomes always zero.
Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint: if both the partial derivatives exists and are continuous in $(0,0)$ then $f$ is differenciable and $f'$ is continuous at $(0,0)$.

Comment: i know this theorem, but since both partial derivatives become 0 in P(0,0) i cant say if they are continious or not without e.g epsilon criteria or something like that. or is it enough to know they are zero hence discontinous?

Comment: And what does it mean for my liner Map to be zero?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: check path $y=x$ for both functions in definition of derivative using limit